# Matching values on the list and comparing value in the columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to iterate on index from file2. If particular index from file2 is in the file1, next I would like to compare value in the 'TotalFat' column on the index level. For below code, I have 'Diff in key' for all entries, not sure why as keys in both files are the same. I will be grateful for your help!

```
for key in file2.index.to_list():
if key in file1.index.to_list():
    if file2['TotalFat'].loc[key] == file1['TotalFat'].loc[key]:
        file2['Diff'] = 'Same'
    else:
        file2['Diff'] = 'Diff'
else:
    file2['Diff'] = 'Diff in key'
```

Comment: Share some sample data, please

Comment: added, thx very much

Answer (score 0):

Example of data in the files:

```
Key Category    Item    Calories    TotalFat
BreakfastEgg McMuffin   Breakfast   Egg McMuffin    300 100
BreakfastEgg White Delight  Breakfast   Egg White Delight   250 8
BreakfastSausage McMuffin   Breakfast   Sausage McMuffin    370 23
BreakfastSausage McMuffin with Egg  Breakfast   Sausage McMuffin with Egg   450 28
```

Key example used as a index:
'BreakfastEgg McMuffin'